# ITMS-90338 gomobile _ptrace rejected by App Store

Tags: ios, go, app-store-connect, ptrace, gomobile

Apple rejected iOS application when i deploy it with framework builded by gomobile. I try update gomobile to last version, but it doesnt help.

**Reason**: *ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Application: _ptrace.*

**Note**:

- Xcode Version 12.2
- iOS 14.2, Target iOS 14.0
- gomobile version +32b2708
- go version 1.12.5

How to disable **_ptrace** symbol in gomobile framework  for passed Apple revision?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31628)? (Any way to try a more-up-to-date version of Go, which is 1.15.x? 1.12 is dirt old.)

Comment: The issue #31628 hints at that it's fixed since 1.13.x

Comment: While we're on it, I've used [this search](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=is%3Aissue+_ptrace) to locate the issue. Please consider doing something like this next time before posting on SO :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix that "_ptrace" glitch by updated to last version of go (gomobile update does not give result).

Thanks kostix by feedback, many issue solution can be founded on official go github page:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues